# Mongo script not modifying collection

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a script that will update the validator object of a mongo document.

Below is my script (index.js)

```
printjson(">> running migration script for version alpha-1.3");

let conn = new Mongo();
let db = conn.getDB("test");

printjson(">>> updating userPool collection");
let validator = db.getCollectionInfos({ name: "userPool" })[0].options.validator;
validator.$jsonSchema.required.push("TESTING");
validator.$jsonSchema.properties["TESTING"] = { 
    bsonType: "array"
};
db.runCommand({ collMod: "userPool", validator: validator });

delete db;
delete conn;

printjson(">> migration script completed");
```

I then execute the script as follows:

```
mongo test index.js
```

The script executes since the printjson is outputted to the console BUT the collections within the database aren't updated.

Any idea why?

Comment: Can you log the response document from the runCommand call?

Comment: "errmsg" : "$jsonSchema keyword 'required' array cannot contain duplicate values"

Comment: It's because I was running against my dev database that already has the fields~!